# How to check if a changeType is "merge" or "branch" when retrieving git changes through Azure DevOps REST Api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am fetching Git changes from Azure DevOps REST Api and want to distinguish if a specific commit was a merge/branch operation. The default changeTypes are: `add, edit, delete` and I couldn't find any reference for "merge" or "branch".

**Is there a built in way to achieve this?**

My query uses the following syntax [from the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1):
`GET https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitId}?api-version=4.1`  
And the response is like:

```json
{
  "parents": [],
  "treeId": "7fa1a3523ffef51c525ea476bffff7d648b8cb3d",
  "push": {
    "pushedBy": {
      "id": "8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
      "displayName": "Chuck Reinhart",
      "uniqueName": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
      "url": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/Identities/8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d",
      "imageUrl": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_api/_common/identityImage?id=8c8c7d32-6b1b-47f4-b2e9-30b477b5ab3d"
    },
    "pushId": 1,
    "date": "2014-01-29T23:33:15.2434002Z"
  },
  "commitId": "be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4",
  "author": {
    "name": "Chuck Reinhart",
    "email": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
    "date": "2014-01-29T23:32:09Z"
  },
  "committer": {
    "name": "Chuck Reinhart",
    "email": "fabrikamfiber3@hotmail.com",
    "date": "2014-01-29T23:32:09Z"
  },
  "comment": "First cut\n",
  "changeCounts": {
    "Add": 2
  },
  "changes": [
    {
      "item": {
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "path": "/.gitattributes",
        "url": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/.gitattributes?versionType=Commit"
      },
      "changeType": "add"
    },
    {
      "item": {
        "gitObjectType": "blob",
        "path": "/.gitignore",
        "url": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/items/.gitignore?versionType=Commit"
      },
      "changeType": "add"
    }
  ],
  "url": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4",
  "remoteUrl": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/commit/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4"
    },
    "repository": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249"
    },
    "changes": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commits/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4/changes"
    },
    "web": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_git/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/commit/be67f8871a4d2c75f13a51c1d3c30ac0d74d4ef4"
    },
    "tree": {
      "href": "https://fabrikam:8080/tfs/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/trees/7fa1a3523ffef51c525ea476bffff7d648b8cb3d"
    }
  }
}
```

If there is no built in way to achieve this, should the `parent` be used as a guidance? Like if it is empty it is a 'branch' operation and if there is two entries in it it is a 'merge'?

### **Update 1**

I can see in the documentation referenced above that there are `merge` and `branch` changeTypes, but when I query a change that was merged the result only contains `edit` or `add`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the parents collection to determine whether it was a merge. Since normal commits just have 1 parent, more than 1 indicates a merge.

From the git documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree#_description)

> A commit object may have any number of parents. With exactly one parent, it is an ordinary commit. Having more than one parent makes the commit a merge between several lines of history. Initial (root) commits have no parents.

Comment: Yes this is what I have figured as well, but what I need to know is how Azure handles these. If this is also stated by Azure than can you provide the relevant documentation from them?